# Memory issue with CFString

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments, cfstring

When I turn off the WiFi during a series of AFNetworking server requests, I am getting increase of memory without any reason. I have provided the memory profile given by instruments. Why is this increasing while not doing anything? How can I get rid of this?

[image: The screen shot of zombie instrument result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the reason. It was a recursive call that retries if network is not available. It solves my issue. But why it is not shown in 'Allocation' or 'Leak' instruments? It is only shown in 'Zombies' instrument.